# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. The app enter an infinite loop state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to build a Slack clone using React and Firebase. everything was smooth until I used The firebase hook "usecollection", the app started entering a state of an infinite loop and I tried everything I know to fix it but to no avail.

Here is my Chat component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ChatInput from './ChatInput';
import { InfoOutlined, StarBorderOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { useCollection } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectRoomId } from '../features/appSlice';
import { styled } from 'styled-components';
import { db } from './firebase';

function Chat() {
  const roomId = useSelector(selectRoomId);

  const [roomDetails] = useCollection(
    roomId && db.collection('rooms').doc(roomId),
     // gets the room's details
  );
  const [roomMessages] = useCollection(
    roomId &&
      db
        .collection('rooms')
        .doc(roomId)
        .collection('message')
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    // gets the room's messages
  );

  console.log(roomDetails?.data());
  return (
    <ChatContainer>
      <Header>
        <HeaderLeft>
          <h4>
            <strong>#{roomDetails?.data().name}</strong>
            <StarBorderOutlined />
          </h4>
        </HeaderLeft>
        <HeaderRight>
          <p>
            <InfoOutlined />
            Details
          </p>
        </HeaderRight>
      </Header>
      <ChatMessages></ChatMessages>

      <ChatInput ChannelName={roomDetails?.data().name} ChannelId={roomId} />
    </ChatContainer>
  );
}
```

And Here is the ChatInput Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from 'styled-components';
import { db } from './firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
function ChatInput({ ChannelId, ChannelName }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!ChannelId) {
      // alert('You need to choose a channel before sending a message ');
      return false;
    }
    db.collection('rooms').doc(ChannelId).collection('messages').add({
      message: input,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      name: 'Omar',
      photoURL:
        'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/AOLn63EOIzg1qeiUmrpgjtKQW5ob6dgKWUn6_pIcjYDHLg=s32-c-mo',
    });
    setInput('');
  };
  return (
    <ChatInputContainer>
      <form>
        <input
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          placeholder={`Message #${{ ChannelName }}`}
        />
        <Button hidden type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
          SEND
        </Button>
      </form>
    </ChatInputContainer>
  );
}
```

The issue happens because I am trying to call the ChannelName in the ChatInput component. It should be working fine but for some reason it is not.

I tried removing the "useCollection" hooks and the problem was gone. so probably the hook is what causing the problem but I don't know what is wrong with it

Here is a picture of the error:

[image]